InvalidCastException when using <Span> to format label text in MAUI
Can I make the <Span/> elements inherit styles from parent <Label/> or freely apply styles in some way?
I've been trying to use <Span/> elements to format <Label.FormattedText/> and I keep getting an InvalidCastException, unless I meet some very specific conditions that I am not familiar with. By default, the <Span/> elements are unstyled and they don't inherit from the parent <Label/>, so I have to completely style those to match all the other label texts in my app.
For example, I cannot use the Style attribute, FontFamily attribute or TextColor attribute for any <Span/> element at all without getting the InvalidCastException notifying that the "Object must implement IConvertible".
For this project I'm trying to have a simple label where one single word is bold and the rest is not:
<Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Some placeholder text for"/>
            <Span Text=" this specific " FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Span Text="issue on StackOverflow"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>

This example works, but as soon as I apply the Style="{StaticResource SpanFormat}" to have the style below applied, I'm getting the InvalidCastException mentioned. The same for TextColor and FontFamily like mentioned.
<Style TargetType="Span" x:Key="SpanFormat">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource PrimaryDark}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="PTSansRegular" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>


The issue arises from trying to make your spans react to light/dark mode. In reality, the entire FormattedString needs to be rebuilt. Therefore, your only XAML option is to place two versions of the FormattedString in the ResourceDictionary and use AppThemeBinding to switch between them. Alternatively, you can move the FormattedString to your view model and trigger OnPropertyChanged() whenever Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged is triggered.

My codes worked fine. Where did you put the style  code?

@StephenQuan I'll go with the ViewModel solution as it allows for more flexibility. Thanks!

@liyu The style is defined in styles.xaml - Did you also set the style attribute for the <Span/> elements? In my questions example I didn't but it should be added.

Yes, but my style code is in  the contentpage.resources node.

Have you solved the problem ?@AlJohn I test the same sample,but it works fine.

@liyu It did not work when I styled inline or in styles.xaml - Haven't tested contentpage.resources but the issue was solved using Stephen Quan's comment (MVVM method).
